# Get last child with specific id using JS, not Jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi am looking to get the last element with a specific id out of various elements with that id.

The idea is to add new rows dynamically through **Javascript, not Jquery**. I have a div with id **newrow**. On clicking **add more rows** button, I want to append the copy of same row through javascript and ajax using the following code:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
        //In the following line, I need to get the last newrow element and add new row in it.
        //responsetext will have another div with id newrow so that another new row can be added to it.
        document.getElementById("newrow").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","newrowcode.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I know the things would work with the Jquery solution, bbut we are using plain javascript for ajax here. Please suggest a solution with this approach.

Comment: By the way, there is a new `fetch` function in JS which aims to replace the old ugly `XmlHttpRequest`

Comment: Don't use the same `id` for elements, `id` is meant to be unique, if you want to group these elements, use the same `className` and then use `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: `=` is for overriding, `+=` for appending

Comment: There's no reason for multiple elements to have the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi am looking to get the last element with a specific id out of various elements with that id.

That's a problem, `id` values **must** be unique. When you break that rule, in theory, browsers can ignore the `id` on subsequent elements (though in practice I've never seen that). I suggest switching to a class, rather than an `id`.

To find the last element matching a selector, you can use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("the-selector");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
```

To **try** to use `id` in this situation, you could use `[id=newrow]` as the selector (not a proper `id` selector like `#newrow`):

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("[id=newrow]");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
```

Again I **do not recommend that**. Make it a class instead, and then use `.newrow`:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".newrow");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
```

All of that said: If the button

```js
var counter = 0;
document.getElementById("add-row").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".newrow");
  var row = list[list.length - 1];
  var newRow = row.cloneNode();
  ++counter;
  newRow.innerHTML = "New row #" + counter;
  row.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, row);
});
```

```html
<div><input id="add-row" type="button" value="Add Row"></div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="newrow">Existing row</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one element with the same ID. A class would make more sense in this case. So instead of `document.getElementById` use `document.getElementsByClassName` and that will return an <s>array</s> HTMLCollection.

Comment: HTMLCollection, not an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection